# LocalStorage keeps getting cleared on refreshing React page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am working on a React app. I store access token in localstorage to authenticate user. But whenever I refresh page, the access token seems to be null. So I keep logging out. I cannot find out what wrong. Please help me with this. Thank you very much.

Here is my login code:

```html
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/admin/documents";

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("Đã xảy ra lỗi!");
    const [emailMessage, setEmailMessage] = useState("");
    const [passwordMessage, setPasswordMessage] = useState("");
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const errRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
        localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setMessage("");
        setEmailMessage("");
        setPasswordMessage("");
    }, [email, password]);

    const validateEmail = () => {
        if (email === "" || email.trim() === "") {
            setEmailMessage("Email không được để trống");
        } else if (!emailRegrex.test(email)) {
            setEmailMessage("Email không hợp lệ");
        }
    };

    const validatePassword = () => {
        if (password === "" || password.trim() === "") {
            setPasswordMessage("Mật khẩu không được để trống");
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setIsLoading(true);

        validateEmail();
        validatePassword();

        if (!emailMessage && !passwordMessage) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify({ email, password }), {
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    withCredentials: true,
                });

                setIsLoading(false);

                if (response.data.status === 401) {
                    setMessage("Email hoặc mật khẩu không đúng!");
                    setStatus(-1);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setStatus(0);
                    }, 4000);
                } else if (response.data.status === 403) {
                    setMessage("Tài khoản không có quyền truy cập!");
                    setStatus(-1);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setStatus(0);
                    }, 4000);
                } else if (response.data.status === 400) {
                    setMessage("Có lỗi xảy ra!");
                    setStatus(-1);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setStatus(0);
                    }, 4000);
                } else {
                    alert("JJJJJJJJ")
                    setMessage("Đăng nhập thành công!");
                    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.data.data.accessToken);
                    localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", response.data.data.refreshToken);

                    const config = {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: "Bearer " + response.data.data.accessToken,
                        },
                    };

                    const res = await getProfile(config);
                    const user = res.data;

                    dispatch(loginAction.setUser(user));

                    setStatus(1);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        navigate("/manager/home");
                        setStatus(0);
                    }, 2000);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setStatus(-1);
                setMessage("Đã xảy ra lỗi!");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setStatus(0);
                }, 4000);
            }
        }
    };
```

And my code to attach token:

```html
useEffect(() => {
        const requestInterceptor = privateAxios.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

                if (!accessToken) navigate("/admin/login");
                else config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

                return config;
            },
            (error) => Promise.reject(error),
        );

        const responseInterceptor = privateAxios.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => {
                if (response.data.status === 401) {
                    if (response.data.message === "User unauthorized. Please log in first.") navigate("/admin/login");
                } else if (response.data.status === 403) navigate("/admin/login");

                return response;
            },
            (error) => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            },
        );

        return () => {
            privateAxios.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
            privateAxios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
        };
    }, [navigate]);
    return privateAxios;
```

Comment: In your first useEffect you are removing your accessToken and refreshToken. As this  useEffect will get called on every reload, this will clear your data.

Comment: This is in my login page so this is not the cause. What leads to my problem is redux state. I use it to check logged in state but I don't know that it is cleared on refreshing. Anyway, thank you :PPP @Vibhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
        localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
    }, []);
```

This code is the culprict, when ever you refresh the page the above code gets executed in the beginning and removes your accessToken and refreshToken.

Remove this code and let me know if it works.

Comment: I've firgured out that redux state is lost after refreshing page. And I use it to check logged in state so I've fixed this. Anyway, thank you so much!!!